# Matlab function for lorentzian fit with global variables

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

I want to fit a Lorentzian to my data, so first I want to test my fitting procedure to simulated data:

```
X = linspace(0,100,200);
Y = 20./((X-30).^2+20)+0.08*randn(size(X));
```

starting parameters

```
a3 = ((max(X)-min(X))/10)^2;
a2 = (max(X)+min(X))/2;
a1 = max(Y)*a3;
a0 = [a1,a2,a3];
```

find minimum for fit

```
afinal = fminsearch(@devsum,a0);
```

afinal is vector with parameters for my fit. If I test my function as follows

```
d= devsum(a0)
```

then d= 0, but if I do exactly what's in my function

```
a=a0;
d = sum((Y - a(1)./((X-a(2)).^2+a(3))).^2)
```

then d is not equal to zero. How is this possible? My function is super simple so I don't know what's going wrong. 
my function:

```
%devsum.m
function d = devsum(a)
global X Y
d = sum((Y - a(1)./((X-a(2)).^2+a(3))).^2);
end
```

Basically I'm just implementing stuff I found here
http://www.home.uni-osnabrueck.de/kbetzler/notes/fitp.pdf
page 7

Comment: A side point: don't use `global` variables to pass data to your function (i.e. `X` and `Y`), rather use anonymous functions. See example 2 from the [`fminsearch` docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminsearch.html)

Comment: What are the values you get for `a0`, are they very different from `[20,30,20]`? Also what is not zero i.e. what is the actual value you are getting for `d`? It shouldn't be exactly zero because your `Y` includes some noise, but it should be very small

Comment: But mostly, you should be checking `d = devsum(afinal)`

Comment: `[112.3817   50.0000  100.0000]` are my values for `a0`, so quite far from `[20, 30 ,20 ]`. My biggest concern is that my function somehow returns zero for no matter what vector a0. When I calculate what I've declared in my function, I get the right result.

I also tried what you suggested and made a function `d=devsum(a,X,Y)`
Then my function gives the right result, so somehow  there is something wrong with these global variables.

However `afinal = fminsearch(@(a0) devsum(a0,X,Y))` fails.
BTW, I don't want this to be like : solve my error, but I want to know what's going wrong.

Comment: So, firstly `a0` doesn't actually get altered the way you had it orginally. `afinal` is the altered (optimized) value. So `devsum(afinal)` should equal `0`, *NOT* `devsum(a0)`

Comment: secondly regaring the anonymous functions it should be: `afinal = fminsearch(@(a) devsum(a,X,Y), a0)`

Comment: Could you use cauchy_pdf instead of defining lorentz?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is usually better to avoid using global variables. The way I usually solve these problems is to first define a function which evaluates the curve you want to fit as a function of `x` and the parameters:

```
% lorentz.m
function y = lorentz(param, x)
y = param(1) ./ ((x-param(2)).^2 + param(3))
```

In this way, you can reuse the function later for plotting the result of the fit.

Then, you define a small anonymous function with the property you want to minimize, with only a single parameter as input, since that is the format that `fminsearch` needs. Instead of using global variables, the measured `X` and `Y` are 'captured' (technical term is doing a [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29) over these variables) in the definition of the anonymous function:

```
fit_error = @(param) sum((y_meas - lorentz(param, x_meas)).^2)
```

And finally you fit your parameters by minimizing the error with `fminsearch`:

```
fitted_param = fminsearch(fit_error, starting_param);
```

Quick demonstration:

```
% simulate some data
X = linspace(0,100,200);
Y = 20./((X-30).^2+20)+0.08*randn(size(X));

% rough guess of initial parameters
a3 = ((max(X)-min(X))/10)^2;
a2 = (max(X)+min(X))/2;
a1 = max(Y)*a3;
a0 = [a1,a2,a3];

% define lorentz inline, instead of in a separate file
lorentz = @(param, x) param(1) ./ ((x-param(2)).^2 + param(3));

% define objective function, this captures X and Y
fit_error = @(param) sum((Y - lorentz(param, X)).^2);

% do the fit
a_fit = fminsearch(fit_error, a0);

% quick plot
x_grid = linspace(min(X), max(X), 1000); % fine grid for interpolation
plot(X, Y, '.', x_grid, lorentz(a_fit, x_grid), 'r')
legend('Measurement', 'Fit')
title(sprintf('a1_fit = %g, a2_fit = %g, a3_fit = %g', ...
    a_fit(1), a_fit(2), a_fit(3)), 'interpreter', 'none')
```

Result:
[image]